# How to run a single test in guard for rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard

I use [guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) to automatically run necessary rspec tests as my files changes, and I love how it works. However, when I'm debugging a file with multiple tests, sometimes I just want an individual test to be re-run. For example, with rspec from the command line:

```
rspec spec/requests/my_favorite_spec.rb:100
```

This will run only the single spec at line 100 in `my_favorite_spec.rb`.

I tried inputting the above into the guard console, but it just ran all the tests as if I had just pressed enter. Is there another syntax in the guard console to run a single spec?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have to argument your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file to accept the `:focus => true` statement.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run :focus => true
end
```

Then you can use

```
it 'does something', :focus => true do
  //your spec
end
```

or

```
describe "something", :focus => true do
  before do
     sign in
     visit page
  end

  it { does something }
  it { does something else }
end
```

If you are going to take that approach, you probably also want to ensure all specs are run if there is no `:focus => true` anywhere, using the [documented approach](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/configuration/run-all-when-everything-filtered):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```

You can do a lot with filters; you might want to have a look at this page: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/filtering

Comment: This does exactly what I needed, and the link was helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: This works, but when I remove `:focus => true` from the `it` block, `guard` says `All examples were filtered out`.  Obviously this fails to satisfy the obvious work flow.  A full solution would run all examples if there were no `:focus` clauses present.

Comment: OK, it turns out you *can* run all specs when there are no `:focus` clauses, via `config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true` in the `RSpec.configure` block.  Here are [the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/configuration/run-all-when-everything-filtered).

Comment: Is there not a way to do this from the command line? I'm trying to make command line functionality work for both guard and for parallel specs

Answer (score 4):

I think you can add the "focus: true" option for the spec you want to run, something like

```
it 'does something', focus: true do
  //your spec
end
```

then you save the file and guard runs only that focused test

when you are finished you just remove "focus: true"

Answer (score 4):

You can use `failed_mode: :focus` in your Guardfile, as described here: https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec#list-of-available-options